# Dired: How to find all files under a directory that match a glob pattern (wildcards)?

Tags: dired, files

Emacs 26.1, Windows 10

In my directory: `d:/TEMP/test/` I has 2 text files. Also in subdirectories I has 2 text files.

[image]

If I want to find all files in directory `d:/TEMP/test/` I do:

```
C-x d d:/TEMP/test/*.txt `RET`
```

As result it show me all text files.
Here result:

[image]

Nice. But if I want to find all **txt** files in subdirectories I use this:

C-x d d:/TEMP/test/*/*.txt `RET`

But It not work. Not find all txt file in all subdirectories. 
Show message:

```
No such directory
```

Why?

Here result:
[image]

After press **Enter**
[image]

Comment: When you hit `RET` your input is taken as a [glob pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)).

Comment: Could you get some example? I need to find all *txt files in current directory and all subdirectories. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Use command `find-name-dired`.

`M-x find-name-dired RET my-directory RET *.txt`

That opens Dired to a listing of all files matching glob pattern `*.txt` in and under directory `my-directory`. The usual Dired features are available in this buffer.

To use `find-name-dired` you must have a UNIX or GNU/Linux `find` command. If you use MS Windows then you can install Cygwin or similar, to provide this.

---

See also library [`find-dired+.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/find-dired%2b.el) for enhanced versions of the Emacs `find-dired-*` commands and some additional ones.

Comment: I found external package for find/replace files by content and extensions in folder and subfolders - "xah-find" - http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/elisp-xah-find-text.html  . It's not depend from external tool like grep/find. It's create on pure Elisp.

Comment: Yes, there are lots of such packages. [Icicles](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Searching_Named_Containers), for example, lets you search lots of kinds of containers - including files, by both container (e.g. file) name and container contents (using, e.g., regexp patterns for both). *But your question was about **Dired** and glob patterns.*